# How can i get the multiple aggregated data from one column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose i have a table as

```
 days  count 

 0      6  
 1      7  
 4      18 
 1      12 
 6       8 
 7      25 
 2      4  
 6      30 
 5      15
```

and i want the result as three column data

```
day_range   total_count   above_threshold_count
  0-3          4                   1     (assuming threshold as 8)
  4-7          5                   2     (assuming threshold as 20)
```

I am able to get the only 2 at a time with the query

```
select 
case when days <=3 then "0-3"
     when days <=7 then "4-7" end as day_range,
count(*)  from t1 
group by case when days <=3 then "0-3"
     when days <=7 then "4-7" end
```

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. column names. Use single quotes for character literals, e.g. '0-3'

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN days <=3 THEN '0-3'
        WHEN days <=7 THEN '4-7'
    END AS day_range,
    COUNT(*) AS total_count,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN days <=3 AND [count] > 8 THEN 1 
            WHEN days <=7 AND [count] > 20 THEN 1
        END
    ) AS above_treshold_count
FROM t1
GROUP BY
    CASE 
        WHEN days <=3 THEN '0-3'
        WHEN days <=7 THEN '4-7'
    END
```

Comment: thanks it also works.. I have also tried the same with some error.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please try below SQL SELECT statement

```
;with cte as (
select
    case when days between 0 and 3 then '0-3' else '4-7' end as day_range,
    case 
        when days between 0 and 3 then
            case when count >= 8 then 1 else 0 end
        else 
            case when count >= 20 then 1 else 0 end
    end as above_threshold
from 
    DayCount
)
select
    day_range,
    count(*) total_count,
    sum(above_threshold) above_threshold_count
from cte
group by day_range
```

Comment: @VirenderDubey its better to accept the best answer for motivation :)

Comment: I have used the First one, mentioned by @Flex in our solution. But i am mentioning the second one is also working fine. I am not 100% sure about the best, as i don't know whether running a subquery (mentioned in 2nd answer) is optimized or not compare to first one.

Comment: In this case CTE or SubQuery, both of them are expected to perform same. But if you use CTE, you can refer it more than once in your SELECT statement or use recursive structures, etc. Additionally, I find CTEs more readable.